# Oracle: Copying Long Raw data from one table to another

Tags: oracle, copy, binary-data

Consider I have two tables Table1 and Table2 having the exact same structure. I want to copy data from Table1 to Table2. Both tables have a field with Long Raw data type. I am using the following insert statement to copy data.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2
SELECT ID, NAME, TO_LOB(IMAGE_DATA) FROM TABLE1
```

The above insert statement is executing with no errors but the resulting data in the Image_Data column has 0 bytes in it; means nothing copied for this field. The data type for Image_Data is (Long Raw) in both tables. Can someone suggest the correct way of copying such data from one table to another.

Many Thanks

Comment: `LONG RAW` has been depricated for almost a decade.  Is there a reason that you aren't using a `BLOB` instead?  That's been the preferred approach since 8.1.5 at least.

Comment: that's the legacy system we have. I don't want to get into that but if left with no other option, I'll give it a try. Any suggestions regarding Long_Raw?

Comment: Short of using the export and import utilities and/or writing a C/ VB/ Java application, I'm not aware of any way to do this with a `LONG RAW`.  If you were using a `BLOB`, you could copy the data just like any other data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why Oracle deprecated LONG and LONG RAW - back in the last millennium - was precisely because of this problem: they were a complete pain-in-the-neck.  Now might be a good time to bite the bullet and move to the modern (but not exactly cutting edge) BLOB implementation.  It depends on how often you're going to work with these tables.  Remember, [to tolerate a problem is to insist on it](http://xprogramming.com/book/books20020208/).

The alternatives are cumbersome.  There are various mechanisms for converting LONGs into something more manageable but they don't work the other way.  One approach which might work for you is:

1. Export `Table1`.  As you like legacy technology you'll want to use EXP rather than Data Pump :)
2. Rename `Table1` to `Table2`.
3. Import `Table1`.

Answer (score 1):

use pl/sql

```
declare
    l long;
begin 
    select long_column into l from some_table where pk = 1;
    insert into some_other_table values (l);
    commit;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

although long or long raw columns shouldn't be used any longer, there are lots of legacy tables to be handled. Check this out:
[Copy Tables with Long/LongRaw columns](http://www.armbruster-it.org/index.php/12-it/pl-sql/22-copy-data-with-long-raw-columns)

```
declare  
   l_rec_long_table long_table%rowtype;
begin
  select *
    into l_rec_long_table
    from long_table a
   where a.long_id = 'some old id';


  insert into long_table
  values
    ('new id',
     l_rec_long_table.long_column);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
DECLARE
   fldLong VARCHAR2(10000);
   idTable MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE.ID_MYTABLE%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (SELECT LONGFIELD_MYTABLE, ID_MYTABLE FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE) LOOP
        fldLong := r.LONGFIELD_MYTABLE;
        idTable := r.ID_MYTABLE;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value field long: ' || fldLong );

        Insert into MYSCHEMA.MY_ANOTHER_TABLE
        (
            ANOTHERFIELD1 [, ANOTHERFIELD2 ...], LONGFIELD_MY_ANOTHER_TABLE
        )
        SELECT FIELD1[, FIELD2 ...], fldLong
        FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
        WHERE ID_MYTABLE = idTable;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```